How to add widgets (e.g. a button) to a window in a C++ application using gtkmm and builder XML file
I am working on a simple example of a GUI  application written in C++ using gtkmm (version 3.24) and an external XML file.
Thanks to the answer to this other question I managed to create an empty window following the approach that I want (a header myWindow.h file for a 'mainWindow' class declaration, another myWindow.cpp file for the class definition, a main.cpp file, and a builder.ui file with the widgets).
My goal is to populate the window with widgets, maybe starting with a simple button. But due to my poor knowledge of C++ I can't.
After some research, I tried to incorporate code from similar examples, in particular from here, and this is what I have so far:
myWindow.h
#pragma once

#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/builder.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:

  MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& p_builder);

protected:

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> m_builder;

};

myWindow.cpp
#include "myWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& p_builder)
: Gtk::Window(cobject)
{
    this->m_builder = p_builder;

    auto pButton = p_builder->get_widget<Gtk::Button>("button1");
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/builder.h>

#include "myWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("builder.ui");

    MainWindow* window = nullptr;

    builder->get_widget_derived("mainWindow", window);

   try
{
        // You then show the window by using you handle (i.e window).
    app->run(*window);
}

catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& bdre)
{
    // specific handling for BuilderError
    std::cout << "Builder error: " << bdre.what() << std::endl;
}

catch(const std::runtime_error& re)
{
    // specific handling for runtime_error
    std::cout << "Other runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
}
catch(const std::exception& ex)
{
    // specific handling for all exceptions extending std::exception, except
    // std::runtime_error which is handled explicitly
    std::cout << "Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
catch(...)
{
    // catch any other errors (that we have no information about)
    std::cout << "Unknown failure occurred. Possible memory corruption" << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}

builder.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.22"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="title">Grid</property>
    <property name="default-width">600</property>
    <property name="default-height">400</property>
    <child>
      <object id="button1" class="GtkButton">
        <property name="label">Button</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">1</property>
          <property name="row">1</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>

When I build this code I get the following error:
myWindow.cpp:14:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Builder::get_widget<Gtk::Button>(const char [8])’
   14 |     auto pButton = p_builder->get_widget<Gtk::Button>("button1");


If I add
Gtk::Button  *addButton;

as protected pointer in the header file myWindow.h, and I use the get_widget() function in the following way
p_builder->get_widget("button1", addButton);

in the constructor definition in file myWindow.cpp, then I am able to build the executable, but then I get the following runtime error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Gtk::BuilderError'
Aborted (core dumped)

with no further information (i.e. the 'try / catch' can not catch the error details).
The syslog reports the following:
systemd-coredump[826232]: Process 826227 (base) of user 1000 dumped core.#012#012Module libzstd.so.1 from deb libzstd-1.5.5+dfsg2-2build1.1.amd64#012Module libsystemd.so.0 from deb systemd-255.4-1ubuntu8.4.amd64#012Stack trace of thread 826227:#012#0  0x000073d024a9eb1c __pthread_kill_implementation (libc.so.6 + 0x9eb1c)#012#1  0x000073d024a4526e __GI_raise (libc.so.6 + 0x4526e)#012#2  0x000073d024a288ff __GI_abort (libc.so.6 + 0x288ff)#012#3  0x000073d024ea5ffe n/a (libstdc++.so.6 + 0xa5ffe)#012#4  0x000073d024ebae9c n/a (libstdc++.so.6 + 0xbae9c)#012#5  0x000073d024ea5a49 _ZSt9terminatev (libstdc++.so.6 + 0xa5a49)#012#6  0x000073d024ebb128 __cxa_throw (libstdc++.so.6 + 0xbb128)#012#7  0x000073d025614130 _ZN3Gtk12BuilderError10throw_funcEP7_GError (libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 + 0x214130)#012#8  0x000073d0253dc34c _ZN4Glib5Error15throw_exceptionEP7_GError (libglibmm-2.4.so.1 + 0x6834c)#012#9  0x000073d02564819e _ZN3Gtk7Builder13add_from_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE (libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 + 0x24819e)#012#10 0x000073d0256481ee _ZN3Gtk7Builder16create_from_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE (libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 + 0x2481ee)#012#11 0x000055e7fb40e6c8 n/a (/home/fabio/Documents/programming/C++/Esperimenti_GTK/GTK4/simple_button/build/base + 0x76c8)#012#12 0x000073d024a2a1ca __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2a1ca)#012#13 0x000073d024a2a28b __libc_start_main_impl (libc.so.6 + 0x2a28b)#012#14 0x000055e7fb40e565 n/a (/home/fabio/Documents/programming/C++/Esperimenti_GTK/GTK4/simple_button/build/base + 0x7565)#012ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64

What am I doing wrong?
Where should I 'call' the widgets defined in the XML file, and how?

Have you tried catching the error and reading the error message?

@jabaa I also used the code suggested here, but the output on the terminal is the same:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132998/1238967

I recommend reading two books: the first book about the basics of C++ and the second book about GTK development. I don't see how you could use a complex library like gtkmm without knowing language features like exception handling. You can start with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try

@jabaa thanks for the advice, those are good references! I am working already on general C++ and on the GTK library, of course.

Your questions suggest, that you you're trying to learn this by trial and error. That won't work. C++ is complex language and gtkmm is a complext library. You should consider a more structured approach, at least two tutorials (C++ and GTK), but I prefer books.

Please don't post code or error stacks in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and post it there. Add the error message from the exception Gtk::BuilderError. You get the error code with Gtk::BuilderError::code

Why have you changed the code? Before the change, you had a runtime error. After your change, you have a compile time error. I would analyze the runtime error.

jabaa after more research I believe that this code is closer to a correct approach. I am away from the computer now, but later I can edit again, reporting both versions.

The accepted answer in your other question was for gtkmm 3.24. The linked code is for gtkmm 4. Which version do you use? If p_builder->get_widget("button_ob", addButton); didn't cause a compile time error, you're very likely not using gtkmm 4, because I can only find this in the docs: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtkmm/classGtk_1_1Builder.html#adae5c2bd11b458b9920020b7602c75c2

@Fabio Why are you trying to get the button in the C++ code if it is defined in the XML file? You should try removing that code first.

@BobMorane that is wonderful! thanks! I left the code as in the 'previous question' that you answered, and just worked on the XML file only. I managed to add one single button, but I have problems adding more. I guess the problem is in adding a grid / layout. Please, when you have time write an answer, possibly with a grid/layout and several widgets. Thanks again!

Are you trying to add buttons dynamically? Specifying them statically in the builder XML is far easier. Nobody is stopping you from adding an empty layout widget to your builder XML and adding buttons to it dynamically.

I managed! I was doing a stupid mistake of not making the grid visible! Now it is working with multiple buttons!
I would like to wait for @BobMorane to write an answer, that I can accept, because most of the solution came from his comment!

The problem in the presented code comes from a poor understanding of how Gtk::Builder works.
Indeed, once the builder is instantiated from the XML file, all the widgets present in the XML file will be created and shown in the window, with no need to 'call' or instantiate them in the code.
A minimal working example, with few widgets (buttons) in the window, is the following:
myWindow.h
#pragma once

#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/builder.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

  MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& p_builder);

protected:

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> m_builder;

};

myWindow.cpp
#include "myWindow.h"

#include <gtkmm/builder.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& p_builder)
: Gtk::Window(cobject), m_builder{p_builder}
{
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/builder.h>

#include "myWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("builder.ui");

    MainWindow* window = nullptr;

    builder->get_widget_derived("mainWindow", window);

    app->run(*window);

   return 0;
}

builder.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object id="mainWindow" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="title">Pippo</property>
    <property name="default_width">400</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>

    <child>
     <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <child>
          <object id="button1" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
          </object>

          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">0</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>

        </child>

        <child>
          <object id="button2" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">1</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object id="button3" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 3</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">2</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object id="button4" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 4</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">0</property>
            <property name="top-attach">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>

     </object>
    </child>

  </object>
</interface>


